Prism launcher uninstalled with upgrade
I upgraded Ubuntu 24.04 to Ubuntu 24.10 and Prism Launcher (a modded Minecraft launcher) got uninstalled. What would be an explanation for that? I just wanted to know because I don't think it interferes with any system packages, I can anyway just install it later. It was installed via apt.

How did you install it before? Flatpak, Appimage or tar.gz?

Apps share more libraries with other apps and the OS in Ubuntu (Linux in general) as compared with Windows. This is called "dependency." If the app, the launcher in your case, requires a specific (old) version of a library that is not available in Ubuntu 24.10 the app may be uninstalled. If a newer version of the app built for 24.10 is available, you can install it again. This does not apply to Snap, Flatpak, and Appimage.

@mook765 I installed it using apt.

@ARaspberry523 That's the reason, it got uninstalled due to dependencies.

It was uninstalled due to dependencies.
